# Why creating files in /dev/shm is not faster than creating files in /tmp?

Tags: bash, files, ram, mktemp

Let's say I have two bash files. The first one is called `diskFile.bash`:

```bsh
for i in {1..10000}
do
    file=$(mktemp)
    cat > $file <<- "SIGN"
        "Hello World"
SIGN
done
echo "finished"
```

And the second one is called `ramFile.bash`:

```bsh
for i in {1..10000}
do
    file=$(mktemp -p /dev/shm/)
    cat > $file <<- "SIGN"
        "Hello World"
SIGN
done
echo "finished"
```

On Linux, files created inside `/dev/shm` are files inside the RAM memory of the system. But if I try executing the first file with `time bash diskFile.bash`, I get:

```
finished
15.56user 5.74system 0:20.25elapsed 105%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6324maxresident)k
```

And with `time bash ramFile.bash`:

```
finished
15.20user 5.37system 0:19.45elapsed 105%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6380maxresident)
```

The difference of time doesn't look like a significant one considering `/dev/shm` should be using RAM memory. Why creating temporary files inside `/dev/shm` is not faster than creating temporary files inside `/tmp`? Is there any way of speeding up the process of creating files using bash?

Comment: Are you sure `/tmp` is on disk? (It’s commonly in memory now.)

Comment: @StephenKitt In my case, I'm sure it's not mounted on RAM since I see that space on my hard disk is used when I put huge files inside it. I've made a different test here creating a tmp folder inside `$HOME` and I've executed the code with `file=$(mktemp -p /home/myuser/tmp)` (to be sure that this folder is in disk)... I still got `15.58user 6.41system 0:20.91elapsed 105%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6392maxresident)k` as result...

Comment: I would guess that temp file are created **first** in RAM, then synchronized to disk at a latter time, outside the scope of yout `time` command.

Comment: That was going to be my next question — does it make any difference if you `sync`? The `/tmp` files are probably only in the page cache (in memory) for the duration of your test.

Comment: (1) You say “… I see that space on my hard disk is used when I put huge files inside it.”  (I presume that “it” refers to `/tmp`.)  How are you measuring / observing “space on [your] hard disk”? (2) This is not really a question *about* bash, and I doubt that it will be answered with bash knowledge.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' It's a question about optimizing the way of creating files in the shell. I'd understand if that was just the time it takes to accomplish this task, but I think it's weird that it takes the same amount of time for creating files in `/dev/shm` and `/any-other-folder`. About the way I'm checking space on disk, I'm using `df -h` and I see the size of my OS partition increasing...

Comment: @StephenKitt Sorry, I didn't get the question "does it make any difference if you `sync`?". How would using `sync` solve this issue?

Comment: It wouldn’t solve it, it would show the real difference between creating files in memory and creating files on disk (by ensuring that you’re actually hitting the disk).

Comment: (1)  Yes, it’s somewhat peculiar that it takes the same amount of time to create files in ``/dev/shm`` and other directories, but …  Can you program in C, C++, Java, Python, or any other programming language?  If so, what happens if you translate your test code into one of those other languages?  If you get results for C (or one of the others) that are radically unlike the results for bash, then you will have a ***really** interesting* question.  Until then, your question is about the file system and the operating system, and (probably) not about bash.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) If your ``/tmp`` directory is really a directory on your root partition, and the free space on `/` goes down when you create files in `/tmp`, you should probably say so.  (3) I accept the terms as pretty much interchangeable, but some people here get annoyed when you refer to directories (in Unix / Linux) as “folders”.

Comment: Unfortunately i dont have an answer- but i have wondered this EXACT same question.  I can also CONFIRM your findings in my real world scripts (some that create 500+ small temporary files).  I have compared results both writing to a directory (non-SSD even) VS to a memory /dev/shm file (same mktmp command),  and i can NEVER find a performance improvement.  I cant say 100%, but via watching output of : iostat -x -m 1   100   ,  (it does *SEEM/Look like* /dev/shm is NOT writting to the disks as opposed to redirection to a file which DOES seem to write to disk ) -- would LOVE an answer! tks

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself the same question. Is /dev/shm/ faster than my home directory or /tmp?

I distrust the bash-loop test. Someone else suggested that this should be done in C/C++.

This is my test:

We have a large server with 3TB RAM, which is currently running under full load, so it is not as fast as it could be. But the background load was 100% stable during this test. The jobs on the server read and write to /dev/shm as well as to the HDD.

First "df /tmp" gives me:

```
tmpfs          1585333764  976564 1584357200    1% /tmp
```

and "df /dev/shm" gives me:

```
tmpfs          1585333764  977168 1584356596    1% /dev/shm
```

The tmpfs tells me that both are in RAM.

The disc I did this test on has this space left:

```
/dev/sdb1        60T     52T  4,9T   92%
```

Code I used to run benchmark test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  const int N=1000000000;

  char * data    = new char [N];
  char * data_in = new char [N];
  
  string   filename="out.txt";
//  string   filename="/tmp/out.txt";
//  string   filename="/dev/shm/out.txt";
  ofstream os(filename.c_str());

  for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
    data[i] = 'A'+ i%20;

  os.write(data, N);
  os.close();

  ifstream is(filename.c_str());
  is.read(data_in, N);

  unsigned long sum;
  for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
    sum += (unsigned char)data_in[i];

  cout << sum << endl;
}
```

I compiled 3 versions using the different output file paths, all with g++ -O3. The compiler I used is:
gcc-Version 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6) (GCC)
The compiler is a bit old, but this should not influence this test, I think.

The HDD are in a huge RAID5, fast SAS, no SSD. The RAID will slow down writing to the disc a bit.

Results:
writing and reading to disc:

```
real    0m5.739s
user    0m1.602s
sys     0m2.541s
```

Writing and reading to tmp:

```
real    0m3.669s
user    0m1.645s
sys     0m2.009s
```

Writing and reading to /dev/shm:

```
real    0m3.639s
user    0m1.633s
sys     0m1.991s
```

I repeated this a few times. The results are highly consistent.

So writing to disc is certain a bit slower than writing to the in memory RAM (/tmp or /dev/shm).
The values are so close together that I think everyone has to test this for her/his system. The fact that I have a RAID could influence the result, but in the end, this is what I want to compare.

So the answer/conclusion that I/O to /dev/shm is slower than to an HDD is not the general answer.